# I have a MultiTrigger in Xamarin form, for a button, it's not working

Tags: xamarin, multitrigger

I have a create-account page in my PCL, with a button that depends on several entry fields.

I want to enable the Create button only when the fields have the proper input.  Here's my markup:

```
<Button Text="Create Account" Clicked="CreateAccountButton_Clicked" IsEnabled="False">
     <Button.Triggers>
          <MultiTrigger TargetType="Button">
               <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference EmailValidator}, Path=IsValid}" Value="True" />
                    <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference PasswordValidator}, Path=IsValid}" Value="True" />
               </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
               <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
          </MultiTrigger>
     </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

I have verified that the validators are setting their IsValid properties to True, yet the button is NOT being enabled.  I am using an Android emulator and Visual Studio 2019.

The code above is identical to several examples I found online.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out.

Comment: Delete the question then, people don't need to read your question and your comment that you don't need help

Comment: Or put your answer so that someone who has the problem can understand it, that would be better, if people are only about looking for help and not helping others then obviously the site like this won't work.

Comment: You are missing the converter. You can take inspiration from this link https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers

Answer (score 0):

In your Xaml :

```
<ResourceDictionary>
   <local:MultiTriggerConverter x:Key="DataHasBeenEnteredTrigger" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

My Example :

```
<Button IsEnabled="False" Text="{localization:Translate login}" Margin="25,0" TextColor="{StaticResource color-fourth}" BackgroundColor="Yellow" Opacity="0.5" FontAttributes="Bold" Command="{Binding GoConnexionCommand}" >
                <Button.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger TargetType="Button">
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference user},
                                      Path=Text.Length,
                                      Converter={StaticResource DataHasBeenEnteredTrigger}}"
                                      Value="true" />
                            <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference password},
                                      Path=Text.Length, 
                                      Converter={StaticResource DataHasBeenEnteredTrigger}}"
                                      Value="true" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
    </MultiTrigger>
</Button.Triggers>
```

Convert Class:

```
public class MultiTriggerConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return false;

        if ((int)value > 0) return true;            
         else return false;   // Input is empty
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Test this and tell me what it looks like!

Best regrads